# Drawing solid bottom triangle

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics, 3d

I'm trying to draw a flat bottom triangle, solid one, but I get a division by zero when I call it like that

```
raster.DrawBottomTriangle(0, 50, 50, 0, -50, 0, Color(1, 0, 0));
```

So I try to draw a flat bottom triangle using the above function, but I get a division by zero.

```
void Rasterizer::DrawBottomTriangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color)
{
    int temp_x;

    // test order of x1 and x2
    if (x2 < x1)
    {
        temp_x = x1;
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = temp_x;
    } // end if swap
    // compute deltas
    float dxy_left = (x2 - x0) / (y2 - y0);
    float dxy_right = (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1);
    // set starting and ending points for edge trace
    float xs = x0;
    float xe = x1;

    // draw each scanline
    for (int y = y0; y <= y2; y++)
    {
        // draw a line from xs to xe at y in color c
        DrawHorizontalLine((int)(xs + 0.5), (int)(xe + 0.5), 50, color);
        // move down one scanline
        xs += dxy_left;
        xe += dxy_right;
    } // end for y

}
```

Comment: What do you precisly want?

Comment: I want to know what I'm doing wrong, the slope has a division of zero, I think the math correct. Correct me If I'm wrong?

Comment: You should ask yourself why y2 is equal to y0 or y1 before giving them as parameters or either check it before making your calculations

Comment: You're dividing by both `(y2-y0)` and by `(y2-y1)`. if y1 == y0 and/or y1 == y2, that's going to be a problem (and you're passing `0` for both `y1` and `y2`).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks. I fixed that. Now the loop condition is always false. I don't know IF I'm rasterizing the triangle correctly ?

Comment: @andreahmed: Well, you are doing things a little unusually, anyway. Most people compute the slope of the line (Delta X/Delta Y). This leads to roughly the same problem, except that it arises for vertical lines instead (mathematically, it makes sense though--a vertical line has infinite slope).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Now I fixed the slope problem. but the loop never occurs for the above parameters. I don't know why ? Is my math correct ?

Comment: @andreahmed "Is my math correct ?" Of course it's not, otherwise you would have your function working. Hint: draw a rectangle with two sides parallel to the x and y axis **on paper** and resolve the intersection of your scan line with the sides by hand - you will discover your errors pretty quickly (2 errors: a vertical line has an infinite slope, a horizontal line intersected with another horizontal line is either "no intersection at all" or "lines are equal").